# What is the maximum likelihood estimate of $p$?

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

$1,2,3,3,4$ is a random sample from $X$ that has the following probability distribution:
$P(X=1)=P(X=2)=1/4$.
$P(X=3)=p$
$P(X=4)=\frac{1}{2}-p$
  Find the Maximum likelihood estimate for $p$
I have solved many problems on finding MLE's and I know only the method of finding the likelihood function and differentiating it. I have no clue how to solve this one.

Comment: What about setting $p=\frac{1}{4}$?
In that case X would have a uniform distribution

Comment: @JejeBelfort It would have uniform distribution. So??? How does it make 1/4 the mle?

Comment: @JejeBelfort : The MLE is something that in general depends on the observed outcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The joint prob is $(1/4)^2p^2(1/2 - p)$. Differentiate w.r.t $p$, set the derivative to $0$ to get $2p(1/2-p)-p^2=0$ i.e. $p-3p^2=0$ i.e. $p=1/3$

Comment: Your answer does not even depend on the sample. How is it possible? And I also didn't understand how did you write the joint probability distribution

Comment: Of course my answer depends on the sample. The likelihood is the joint prob I have written. What is the likelihood? It is $P(X_1=1)P(X_2=2)P(X_3=3)P(X_4=3)P(X_5=4)$

Comment: @idpd15 : The answer reports a "joint probability". Think about where that expression came from. It came from the sample.

Answer (score 2):

It is a multinomial distribution, i.e., the likelihood function is 
$$
\mathcal{L}(p;\mathrm{x} =( 1,2, 3, 3, 4) ) = \frac{5!}{1!1!2!1!}\frac{1}{4^2}p^2(1/2- p),    
$$
the log likelihood is 
$$
\ell(p) = \ln \left( \frac{5!}{1!1!2!1!}\frac{1}{4^2}\right) + 2\ln p+\ln(1/2-p),
$$
$$
\ell'(p)|_{p= \hat{p}} = \frac{2}{p}- \frac{1}{1/2-p}=0 \to \hat{p}=1/3.
$$
Checking the sign of second derivative
$$
\ell''(p)|_{p= 1/3} = -\frac{2}{1/9} - \frac{1}{(1/2-1/3)^2}<0.
$$

Comment: Alternatively, one could say that the function $p\mapsto p^2(1-p)$ is $0$ when $p=0$ or $p=1$ and is positive when $0<p<1$ and is continuous, so it must have an absolute maximum somewhere between $0$ and $1$, and since it's differentiable everywhere, the maximum must occur where the derivative is $0$. If there is only one point where the derivative is $0$ then that must be where the absolute maximum is.